# JavaScript ajax didn't working.Where am I going wrong?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
     <div class="media-bottom">

                        @Html.TextAreaFor(model => model.Message, new { @class = "ui form", @rows = "5", @maxlenght = "300", @placeholder = "Paylaşmak istedikleriniz" })
                    </div>
                    <br />
                    <div class="footer-logo">
                        <button class=" mini ui right labeled right floated icon button" id="Button_Click" onclick="javascript: Button_Click();">
                            <i class="right arrow icon"></i>
                            Paylas
                        </button>

 <div class="container bootstrap snippets bootdey downlines">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12">
                <section class="widget">
    
                    <div class="widget-body">
                        <div class="widget-top-overflow windget-padding-md clearfix bg-info text-white">
    
                        </div>
                        <div class="post-user mt-n-lg">
                            <span class="thumb-lg pull-left mr media-object">
                                <img class=" img-circle" src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_3.jpg" alt="...">
                            </span>
                            <span class="thumb-lg pull-right mr star">
                                <img src="~/Content/img/star.png" />
                            </span>
                            <div class="Thanksicon">
    
                            </div>
    
    
                            <div class="namespace">
                                <h5 class="mt-sm fw-normal text-black txt post">
                                    @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.FullName)
                                    <br />
                                    <small class="text-black text-light departmen post">@Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Departmen)</small>
                                </h5>
                            </div>
    
                        </div>
                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <div class="text-light fs-mini m" id="Label1">
                            <div id="label1">
                                <p class="article">
                                    @Html.DisplayTextFor(model=>model.Message)
                                </p>
                              
                            </div>
                            <div class="thanksnames">
                                <span class="thumb-xs avatar mr-sm">
                                    <img class="img-circle thank" src="https://bootdey.com/img/Content/user_2.jpg" alt="...">
                                </span>
                                <div class="mt-sm fw-normal text-black " id="person"> <small class="text-black text-light">Rose Tyler</small></div>
                            </div>
                            <br />
                            <div class="img"></div>
                            <div class="fs-mini text-muted text-right"><time class="time-table-top"></time></div>
    
                        </div>
    
                    </div>
                    
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

This is my javascript

```
  $(function () {
            $('#Button_Click').on('click', function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("Share")',
                    data: {
                        fullname: $("#username").val(),
                        departmen: $("#departmen").val(),
                        textarea: $(".ui.form").val()
                    },
                    datatype: "json",
                    success: function (data) {
                        
                        $('.downlines').html(result);
                    }, error: function (data) {

                    }

                });
            });
        });
```

This is my controller httppost

```
  [HttpPost]
        private JsonResult Share(SocialMedia data,string id)
        {
            var employee = _employeeRepository.GetById(id);
            ViewBag.IsOwner = id == Session.GetEmployeeNo();
            if (Session["MediaList"] == null)
            {
                Session["MediaList"] = new List<SocialMedia>();
            }
            var fullname = data.FullName;
            var departmen = data.Departmen;
            var textarea = data.Message;
            foreach (MediaList list in data.MediaLists)
            {

                list.FullName = fullname;
                list.Departmen = departmen;
                list.Message = textarea;
                list.Date = DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime();             
                if(data.Photo!=null)
                {
                    list.Photo = data.Photo;
                    string fileName = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(list.Photo);
                    list.Photo = "~/Image/" + fileName;
                    string _path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"),fileName);
                    
                }
            }
            return Json(new { data = PartialView("~/Views/SocialMedia/DisplayTemplates/MediaList.cshtml") });
           // return PartialView("~/Views/SocialMedia/DisplayTemplates/MediaList.cshtml",
            //return Json(new { success = true, message = GlobalViewRes.CreatedSuccessfully }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);

        }
```

When I write an article and press the button, I want the page to appear below without refreshing and I want it to be repeated. It should be with the whole design. But when I press the button, I made ajax, but my ajax does not work, where am I going wrong?
Sorry for my English:)

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: "doesn't work" is meaningless. Do you see errors, if so which? Did you use the browser Dev Tools, esp. the `Console` and `Network` tabs, what do they show?

Comment: I didn't see error.I can click the button but it's doing nothing

Answer (score 0):

```
                success: function (data) {
                    
                    $('.downlines').html(result);
                }, error: function (data) {

                }
```

You handle the data named 'data'. Then you are trying use it like 'result'. What is result, where is it came from? Whatever, try this

```
$('.downlines').html(data)
```